# Getting the values in the list based on separators

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I want to search a specified string using regex search expression. I wrote the following code. But, it shows an error. In the separator, the value to be searched is loaded. If it's there, it should be loaded to another list.

#### Code

```
import re
value_to_separate = ["prinec-how,are_you&&smile#isfine1"]

separator = ["&&smile","prinec-","#isfine1",",are_you","-how,are"]

for sep in separator:
    for val_sep in value_to_separate:
        val_sep = re.search(separator,val_sep) 
        print(val_sep)
```

Required output:

```
["&&smile","prinec-","#isfine1",",are_you","-how,are"]
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely do not need a regex. It's really overkill. Use a list-comprehension:

```
[x for x in separator if x in value_to_separate[0]]
```

**Code**:

```
value_to_separate = ["prinec-how,are_you&&smile#isfine1"]
separator = ["&&smile","prinec-","#isfine1",",are_you","-how,are"]

print([x for x in separator if x in value_to_separate[0]])
```

which outputs in the required format:

```
['&&smile', 'prinec-', '#isfine1', ',are_you', '-how,are']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `separator` list to `re.search` instead of the individual separator item `sep`.
Change `re.search(separator,val_sep)` to `re.search(sep,val_sep)`
Also use `val_sep.group(0)` to get your actual match string
Then your code will change to.

```
import re
value_to_separate = ["prinec-how,are_you&&smile#isfine1"]

separator = ["&&smile","prinec-","#isfine1",",are_you","-how,are"]


for sep in separator:
    for val_sep in value_to_separate:

        val_sep = re.search(sep,val_sep)
        print(val_sep.group(0))
```

And the output will be.

```
&&smile
prinec-
#isfine1
,are_you
-how,are
```